# HTML5 Animation using CreateJS doesn't work with iPad

Tags: html, ipad, animation, sprite, createjs

I'm working on an animation using CreateJS and spritesheet, but I don't understand why that don't work with iPad.
That works fine with Chrome browser.
The CreateJS framework should work with iOS.

You can find my code here:

> Link no more available

Do you have any idea?

Otherwise, do you have any other solution to create HTML5 animation for iPad from the web?
In addition, I need to add sound to this animation with synchronization with the animation, so the animation must not lag, I need perfect performances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my first answer was not helpful. I took a deeper look here, and the issue is probably because of the size of the PNG. Your PNG is currently 4096x2048, which is double the acceptable size for iOS.

Ensure your images are less than 2048x2048 - you can use Zoë to export them from Flash, which will give you multiple images.
http://createjs.com/zoe

Cheers.